# create a column with default value as null in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

I want to create a column with default value as null and when any operation is performed it should change to 0. How do i do this in mysql database?

Comment: measn I have to update that column to 0 on  function call...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here example how to add colum in existing table with default value

```
ALTER TABLE `test1` ADD `no` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL ;
```

When you call function then you have to write following query

```
UPDATE test1 SET `no` = '0' WHERE `test1`.`id` =your_id;
```

Comment: i already have a table. and i want to add column with default value null.

Comment: say add column with default value null to existing table

Comment: @KedarB when you ask question then mention all these things

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
PRIMARY KEY(id),
test_id INT,
cost FLOAT(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
);
```

each time when you do some operation on that you need to update it as @Sadikhasan

or write a trigger that will update it to zero automatically.

if the operation you want to perform is read then write trigger on `ON SELECT`

if the operation you want to perform is update then write trigger on `ON UPDATE`

like wise for others.